Question about prime elements in the gaussian numbers
Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]:=\{a+ib : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ denote the gaussian numbers. Let $N$ denote the euclidean function $N(z):=z \overline{z}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ denote the positive prime numbers.
Reading about those numbers i have learned two things:

Let $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ be a prime element (in $ \mathbb{Z}[i]$), then either $N(\pi)=p \in \mathbb{P}$ or $\pi$ is associated to $p$.

Let $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$. If $N(\pi)=p \in \mathbb{P}$, then $\pi$ is a prime element in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.


I have been trying to "sort" does statements in my mind. So I do not missinterpret the them. I am interested if I got the meaning of those two statements correct. So if anything seems odd/wrong or there is something I did not recognize that one should, please mention it.
Here is what I think Point 1. and 2. are saying:
From "Statement 2":
Given some $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, one possible way to show that $\pi$ is prime (in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$) is to check if $N(\pi) \in \mathbb{P}$.
But if $N(\pi) \notin \mathbb{P}$, I can not conclude that $\pi$ is not-prime (in $ \mathbb{Z}[i]$), since "Statement 1" says that $\pi$ could also be associated to $p \in \mathbb{P}$.
In $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ the units are $+1,-1,+i,-i$.
And if $\pi$ is associated to $p \in \mathbb{P}$, i.e. $\pi= u p$, for $u$ a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $p \in \mathbb{P}$, then obviously $N(\pi)=p^2 \notin \mathbb{P}$.
Some further thoughts:
So if one wants to be able to decide if $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is prime (in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$) one needs to find a characterization when $p \in \mathbb{P}$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.
Then to check if $\pi in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is prime (in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$)
one can first check if $N(\pi)=p \in \mathbb{P}$. If so, then $\pi$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.
If not, then we need to check if $\pi$ is associated to $p$.
If not, then $\pi$ is not-prime (in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$).
If it is associated to $p$ we need to check if $p$ also is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.
If $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then so is $\pi$.
If $p$ is not-prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then neither is $\pi$.

The members of $\mathbb N$ that are primes in the Gaussian integers are those that are primes in $\mathbb Z$ and $\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

@RobertIsrael Thank you for that information!
